# Google Play Store "Bad Behaviour" issue

Tags: android, google-play

I've got an app that's been flagged for "Bad Behaviour" by the Google app store. I've checked the crash logs and do see 7 crashes on Android 11 that's affecting 3 users (with the last crash happening 18 hours ago) while the app itself has 98.7% daily sessions without crashes.

I'm not sure if this warrants a severe sounding flag (or if anyone has experienced it). Can someone also translate this explanation I found?

[image: Google Play Store Screenshot]

Comment: The explanation says that, because of the uncertainty associated with this measure, despite your app shows a crash level above the normal limit, it is not sure it is behaving improperly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play says it is "Bad Behaviour" as your app has more crashes than the 1.09% mark. This does not necessarily mean that your app is behaving improperly, as there is uncertainty associated with this measurement, and therefore if you do not have many users for your app, it may be coincidental that a few of them have done something to get a crash, but, if you had a larger sample size, the crash rate would have been smaller.